# Possible scenarios for Unix domain sockets interruption

Tags: socket, unix-sockets

When using `TCP` & `UDP` sockets, there are many scenarios which cause connection interruption (slow connection, network reset, etc).
Is there any possible situation which an `unix domain socket` automatically disconnects or interrupts because of an external reason?
Should developers consider possible interruption in their codes?

Comment: Without even considering the full question, a developer should _always_ consider and expect the unexpected, including interruptions. So the simple answer is yes, expect to handle such a case, even if it's not _supposed_ to be possible. Errors and bugs happen. And finding them is much harder when you do not write your code from the start to be prepared for them to happen.

Comment: Murphy's Law applies to programming. Anything that can fail, will fail, usually at the least convenient time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion guys, but my question is more than just "consideration".

Comment: It's always possible that server will terminate unexpectedly, no
matter what type of socket or IPC mechanism is used.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk and where that possibility comes from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always possible that server will terminate unexpectedly, no
matter what type of socket or IPC mechanism is used. It can happen for
many different reasons, for example:

- it may crash because of software bug, for because due to
  segmentation fault or failed assertion
- it may eat too much memory and can get killed by Linux OOM killer
  (it's very easily reproducible in virtual machine)
- it may be killed erroneously by another user. Linux is multi-user
  system and it's possible that someone could accidentally killed your
  process, say they wanted to type `kill 1112` but typed `kill 1111`
  instead

> Should developers consider possible interruption in their codes?

Yes, they always should. Read manpage of the function you're going to
use and read all possible values of errnos that the function can set
and always prepare for the worst.